# How do I make my code Javascript run in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I included a script in my html file for JavaScript. I'm trying to make a version of the game Pig. However, despite using onClick features to call my functions, none of them appear to work, and only the html code works. This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .dice{
            background-color: rgb(102, 255, 255);
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border-style: solid;
        }

        h1{
            font-family: "Verdana";
            color: (102, 255, 255);
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        var turn1; //The collection of all points gathered in player1's turn, until player rolls a 1
        var turn2; //The collection of all points gathered in player2's turn, until player rolls a 1
        var p1 = 0; //Player1 (human) score
        var p2 = 0; //Player2 (computer) score
        var pts; //the value from the dice

        function score(){
            text("Player 1 Score: "); //Will display player1 score
            text("Player 2 Score: "); //Will display player2 score
        }

        function skip(){ //Function will run if player clicks to skip
            //p1 = p1 + turn1;
            turn2 = 0;
            pts = random(1,6);
            if (pts == 1){ //Sets turn value to 0 and switches to player1's turn
                textFont("Verdana", 100);
                console.log("1", 500, 200);
                turn2 = 0;
                p2 = p2;
            }
            else if (pts > 1){ //Sets turn2 value to points collected, and adds it to player2's points
                textFont("Verdana", 100);
                text("1", 500, 200);
                turn2 = turn2 + pts;
                p2 = p2 + turn2;
                return p2;
            }
            else{}
        }

        function roll(){ //Function will run if player clicks to roll dice
            turn1 = 0;
            pts = random(1,6); //Set the dice value to a random number from 1 to 6
            if (pts == 1){ //Sets turn value to 0 and switches to player2's turn
                turn1 = 0;
                p1 = p1;
                textFont("Verdana", 100);
                text("Your turn has ended!");
                skip();
            }
            else if (pts > 1){ //Sets turn1 value to points collected, and adds it to player1's points
                textFont("Verdana", 100);
                text(pts, 350, 200);
                turn1 = turn1 + pts;
                p1 = p1 + turn1;
                return p1;
            }
            else{}
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="score();">
    <h1>Pyg!</h1>
    <div>
        <button onClick="roll();" style="cursor: pointer">Roll</button>
        <button onClick="skip();" style="cursor: pointer">Skip</button>
        <div class="dice"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any error in your browser console?

Comment: A function named `text` is missing in your code.

Comment: Also change `onClick` to `onclick`.

Comment: `text` and `random` is not defined in your javascript

Comment: Your script is incomplete. There are functions that are called without being declared — such as **random**, **textFont** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you posted your complete code?. I tried running your piece of code, it does not have the random() function and throws error. Please add that function.

If you are trying to add a random number between 2 digits in the step random(1,6), add the below function to your script

```
function random(min,max){Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min}
```

*note: replace the min and max with your minimum and maximum value between which the number need to generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use random number you have to use the Math library, like this `Math.random(1,6);`

I've suposed that `text = document.getelementById("");`